# Sencha Cmd: Sencha Touch Production Build fails with Cannot call method 'getOrientation' of undefined

Tags: extjs, build, sencha-touch

Sencha Touch 2.3.1 + Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.45 .

After building for production, blocking javascript error appears in the browser when launched:

> Cannot call method 'getOrientation' of undefined

Works perfectly in development environment.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

probably Sencha Cmd does not load some dependencies that the standard loader does load. Check your javascript console in development for warnings like these:

```
[WARN][Anonymous] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'Ext.viewport.Default'; consider adding 'Ext.viewport.Default' explicitly as a require of the corresponding class
```

I think Cmd cannot find the viewport class, try adding it to the 'requires' array in your app.js to see if that solves your problem. Otherwise try to trace the line where the error is thrown (the getOrientation call) and paste some of that code here.

Cheers,
Rob